# Is there a way to find the square of an arctan MacLaurin series without manually calculating the derivatives?

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, taylor-expansion, euler-maclaurin

I got this question from my calculus 2 textbook:

[image]

We are also given this known series:

[image]

Is there anyway to calculate `arctan^2(x)` using this table of already-solved series? I know we can manually derive it with a bunch of differentiation, but I'm assuming there's a faster way using the table that I just can't find.

Thanks.

Comment: Just multiply the given  "polynomial" with itself (find the first few terms).

Comment: @DavidMitra Ok so would I do: (x)^2 - [(x^3)/3]^2 + [(x^5)/5]^2 - etc... (sorry, not sure how to format). This doesn't get the right answer they have listed.

Comment: @thisdude19129: what exactly did you multiply with what to get that result?

Comment: @MartinArgerami I multiplied each progressive value from the table of known arctan(x) given (second image). Is that incorrect?

Comment: Call the series $P$. The square is $xP-(x^3/3)P+\cdots$ (distributive law). Simplify further, keeping in mind you only need a few terms to identify the answer.

Comment: @thisdude19129: so you think that $(1-x)^2=1-x^2$?

Comment: @DavidMitra So I have the whole series, P, which it makes sense to multiply against the whole series in that way, but I'm not sure how. I thought each term would multiply against itself (ie: term 1 * term 1 + term 2 * term 2 ...). How do I multiply the whole of the series, P, against a single term of the other series?

Comment: @MartinArgerami I don't think so. I believe the left = $1-2x+x^2$. Is this what I have to use in the question?

Comment: @thisdude19129: you believe correctly. Now are you aware that your last two comments (to David and me) contradict each other?

Comment: Going to be honest. I don't know what's going on. Sorry if I offended you.

Comment: You have not offended me. You just need to learn to multiply polynomials.

Comment: Distribute: $xP=x(x-x^3/3+\cdots)=x^2-x^4/3+\cdots$. (Add like terms from $-(x^3/3)P$...)

Comment: @DavidMitra Thanks! That works!

Answer (score 1):

$\newcommand{\bbx}[1]{\,\bbox[15px,border:1px groove navy]{\displaystyle{#1}}\,}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\,{#1}\,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\,{#1}\,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\dd}{\mathrm{d}}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{{\displaystyle #1}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,\mathrm{e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\ic}{\mathrm{i}}
 \newcommand{\on}[1]{\operatorname{#1}}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\,{#1}\,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\,{#2}\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\sr}[2]{\,\,\,\stackrel{{#1}}{{#2}}\,\,\,}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{\mathrm{d}^{#1} #2}{\mathrm{d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\,{#1}\,\right\vert}$
\begin{align}
\color{#44f}{\arctan\pars{x}} & =
\left.\int_{0}^{x}{\dd t \over 1 + t^{2}}\right\vert_{\, -1\ \leq\ x\ \leq\ 1}\,\,\, =
\sum_{n = 0}^{\infty}\pars{-1}^{n}\int_{0}^{x}t^{2n}\,\dd t
\\[5mm] & =
\bbx{\color{#44f}{\sum_{n = 0}^{\infty}{\pars{-1}^{n} \over 2n + 1}\,
x^{2n + 1}}} \\ &
\end{align}